# Classifier to Predict activities taking place

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have multiple datasets here that i took from Kaggle. There are multiple csv files and each csv file is made specifically for sit, stand, walking, running etc. The data is taken from sensors like accelerometers and gyroscopes. The values in datasets are of axis like x, y and z.

Sample Data

[image]

Here is a sample dataset of jogging. Now i need to make classifiers in my program so that my program can detect itself whether the data is of jogging, sitting, standing etc. I want to mix all the datasets in a single csv file and then upload it into my webapge and then i want the javascript code to start detecting whether a particular row is of sitting, standing, jogging etc. I don't want any code help but instead i just need a little explanation or a way to start coding it. How can i started making such classifier? I know it is kind of broad question but i think i have tried to explain myself in best way possible. Once my program has detected every row with specific activity it will count all the activities separately and then show it in a table format in webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer properly to your question, it would be very helpful to know which is your level of understanding and experience with  machine learning.

If you are a beginner I would suggest to try to run and understand a couple of tutorials that can be easily found on the web.

If you need an idea of which is the "standard" approach for machine learning development, I will try to give you a general idea of the process.

You can summarize the process in these main steps:

Data pre-processing-> Data splitting -> Feature selection -> Model Training -> Validation -> Deployment

Data pre-processing is meant to clean and format the data: removing NA values, decision about categorical variables, outlier analysis,.... This is a complex step that depends on the application. In your case I would start checking that the data in the different data-sets are homogeneous, i.e. the features have the same meaning across csv and corresponding features respect the same distribution. While the meaning of each feature should be explained in the description of your csv, the check of the distributions could be easily done plotting the box-plots for each feature and csv. If distributions of the same feature across different csv files don't overlap you should investigate further the issue.

An important step in the design of a good model is the splitting of the data. You should split your data in training/validation set (training/validation/test for a more comprehensive approach). This step allows you to train your model on the training set and test the model on the validation set computing unbiased performance of your model. I suggest here to become familiar with concepts as: Cross Validation, stratified-cross-validation, nested-cross-validation for hyper-parameter tuning, overfitting, bias,.... The Validation of the model will give you an idea of the expected performance that it will have on unseen data. If you are considering the use of more than one model, you can use the validation results to choose the "best" one. I suggest here a comparison using the confidence interval or if possible a significance test (e.g t-test, anova,...). Before the deployment the model is trained on all the available data.

The choice of the model depends on the data that you are using: number of samples, number of features, type of variable (numerical, categorical),....

I'm not an expert of javascript, but I believe (just a feeling) that python and R are more common choices for developing Machine learning applications. Both have libraries specifically developed for the task and you can find a lot of materials and tutorial around.

With a bit of more context I think that I could be more specific.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot roberto. Apparently my level is a beginner and i have got time of a few months to get a complete understanding of machine learning concepts. I am watching a few tutorials these days on how to train my datasets but now as you suggest to split my data so i will tryo to first split and then train my model.
Above you told me that to check if my data is homegenous and yes i can confirm it that the data is homeogenous since i tried plotting it on an online graph plotting utility and the features were same across each csv files with minor changes.